# How to convert decimal to hexadecimal variable?

Tags: powershell

I have lots of files bmp and jpg and need to extract file name without extension, write a specific text before, hexadecimal variable after and put it in a text file named `list.txt`

For example, files are: `picture1.bmp`, `picture2.spr`, `picture3.bmp`

I extract text name without extension, put before a specific text and after the extract name a hexadecimal variable, so it's done this in `list.txt`:

```
abc picture1 0x7f020000

abc picture2 0x7f020001

abc picture3 0x7f020002
```

I don't know how to write the hex string in `list.txt` because my script converts it in base10.

My script creates `list.txt` like this:

```
abc picture1 2130837504

abc picture2 2130837505

abc picture3 2130837503
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
$a=".field public static final "

$b=":I = "

$c= 0x7f01ffff

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.bmp,*.spr | ForEach-Object {$a+$_.BaseName+$b+(++$c)} | Out-File list.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use hex values, use [standard numeric format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) string `x`. Powershell's able to interpret hex value as an integer, so you need to call int's ToString() method for conversion.

The standard formater doesn't include `0x` prefix, so add it via extra catenation.

Like so,

```
gci  | % {$a+$_.BaseName+$b+'0x'+(++$c).tostring('X')}
# Output
.field public static final bar:I = 0x7F0200D2
.field public static final foo:I = 0x7F0200D3
.field public static final zof:I = 0x7F0200D4
```

Answer (score 13):

If you want to just convert a decimal number (or integer-type variable) to a hex string, it can be done any of these ways:

```
"{0:X}" -f <number or variable>
[System.String]::Format("{0:X}",<number or variable>)
[System.Convert]::ToString(<number or variable>,16)
(<number>).ToString("X")
<variable>.ToString("X")
```

Comment: Which version of Powershell is this?  I'm using V5 - only the first 2 methods work.

Comment: I'm using 5.1 and all the methods work for me.

Answer (score 1):

### Round Trip:

**From 4 Digit Hex to value, and then back to 4 Digit Hex**
When generating human readable output, it may be desirable have the hexadecimal numbers padded with leading zeros, ensuring each output is the same length. This example demonstrates how to use the `-f` operator to accomplish this task:

```
'0x00F2', '0x4A5B', '0x0CDE', '0x000A' | Foreach-Object {
    [int]$Val   = [int]$_
    "Original   = {0}"      -f $_
    "Decimal    = {0,6}"    -f $Val
    'Round trip = 0x{0:X4}' -f $Val
    ''
}
```

Output of above code:

```
Original   = 0x00F2
Decimal    =    242
Round trip = 0x00F2

Original   = 0x4A5B
Decimal    =  19035
Round trip = 0x4A5B

Original   = 0x0CDE
Decimal    =   3294
Round trip = 0x0CDE

Original   = 0x000A
Decimal    =     10
Round trip = 0x000A
```